# Timeouts with disposers

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Say that there's a library that provides a `connect()` method that can sometimes take an awfully long time due to the server you're connecting to:

```
var stream = require('stream')

function connect() {
  return Promise.delay(Math.random() * 60000)
    .return(stream.PassThrough())
    .disposer(function(conn) { conn.end() })
}
```

Note the use of `disposer()` which makes sure that the connection is closed after being used.

Now, you're in a situation where you need to `connect()`, but time out within 5s if the connection can't be made.

So you try:

```
Promise.using(connect().timeout(5000), function(conn) {
  console.log('Hello world')
})
```

Which obviously does not work since `connect()` returns a `Disposer`.

Oh, I'll just put the timeout inside the using block, you might naively think. Well, that won't work either since we'll only ever enter the block once the connection is established.

So finally you try:

```
Promise.using(connect(), function(conn) {
  console.log('Hello world')
})
.timeout(5000)
```

This, of course, works. However, we're not fortunate enough to have a simple `console.log` be our task. Instead, it looks more like:

```
Promise.using(connect(), function(conn) {
  // Do an awfully long task that takes 2 minutes
})
.timeout(5000)
```

Now the timeout becomes unusable again since the awfully long task naturally takes an awfully long time, causing the timeout to trigger every time.

Is there any way to actually write this in some idiomatic way that doesn't require changing `connect()` to include the timeout?

Comment: Pass the timeout as an argument to the connect function.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm interested in solving this for a case where I have no control over `connect()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
function connect(timeout) {
  return Promise.delay(Math.random() * 60000)
    .return(stream.PassThrough())
    .timeout(timeout)
    .disposer(function(conn) { conn.end() })
}
```

as `Promise.using(connect(5000), …)`

---

If you cannot change `connect`, you might be able to apply the following hack:

```
var connection = connect();
connection = connection.promise().timeout(5000).disposer(connection.data());
Promise.using(connection, …);
```

Notice the `Disposer` interface is undocumented.

Comment: I have no control over `connect()`, it can't be changed.

Comment: How so? It's the natural place for a timeout to be instantiated, so maybe you should request that as a feature from whomever can change it.

Comment: What I posted is just an example that I hoped was easy to understand. What I actually have in this particular case is a `shell()` command. It's being used in both `shell('echo 1')` (short lived) and `shell('while true; do echo 1; sleep 1; done')` (long lived) style. While I want to make sure that the connection gets closed at the end, there is no upper limit to how long the processing might take. Therefore it doesn't make sense to put a timeout in `shell()` directly as there may be cases where I definitely do not want a timeout, and passing `Infinity` doesn't seem very idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `.data()`, at the very least it should be possible to put the original disposer back there even if you end up ripping it out temporarily, could be good enough in this case.

Comment: disposers are stable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks, but is it a public interface? Is there any documentation?

Comment: The whole point of a disposer is that it's an opaque structure - so you don't pass it around to the wrong place by mistake.